# Is there a way to list the available XMLPullParser features on the current Android device?

Tags: android, xml-parsing, xmlpullparser

I'm using XMLPullParser to parse XML, and I want to use the XmlPullParser.FEATURE_PROCESS_DOCDECL feature. This works great on my Galaxy Nexus / JB, but on the emulator with Froyo, I get an "unsupported feature" exception.

The feature is not mandatory, but I would like to use it on phones who can. Is there a way to list the available features on the current device, or make the XmlPullParserFactory not crash if a feature is unavailable, and just ignore it ?

**Edit** : Here's the exact error I get, as well as my code

> 10-04 06:45:51.107: W/System.err(309):
>   org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParserException: could not create parser:
>   org.kxml2.io.KXmlParser: org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParserException:
>   unsupported feature:
>   http://xmlpull.org/v1/doc/features.html#process-docdecl
>   (position:START_DOCUMENT null@0:0) ;  10-04 06:45:51.137:
>   W/System.err(309):    at
>   org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParserFactory.newPullParser(XmlPullParserFactory.java:199)

```
XmlPullParserFactory factory;
XmlPullParser xpp;

factory = XmlPullParserFactory.newInstance();
factory.setNamespaceAware(true);
factory.setFeature(XmlPullParser.FEATURE_PROCESS_DOCDECL, true);
factory.setFeature(XmlPullParser.FEATURE_PROCESS_NAMESPACES, true);
xpp = factory.newPullParser(); // Exception is thrown here
```

Comment: post your log cat please

Comment: FYI, I grepped for it, http://grepcode.com/search?query=FEATURE_PROCESS_DOCDECL+android&start=0&entity=project&n=, and it's been there since 1.5 so I think you have a different problem.

Comment: @Simon although the final static String exists since 1.5, it's implementation may not exist for as long.

Comment: Has this problem ever been solved?

Comment: well for now I don't add any feature as I never found a way to see if a feature is implemented or not